# Lifetime error after upgrade of Anchor and Solana

Tags: anchor, rust, lifetimes

This code built ok previously using Anchor Build, but after upgrade of Anchor and Solana I am getting lifetime errors on build.  Can anyone help point me in the right direction?
[image]

use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use crate::{ Game, MoveAction, PlayerGameRecord, TurnMovesRecord, Coordinates, Army };
pub use crate::errors::ErrorCode;

pub fn submit_player_turn(_ctx: Context, _turns: Vec) -> Result<()> {

```
let player_turn = &mut _ctx.accounts.turn_moves_record;

//If this player has already submitted a turn then return error
if _ctx.accounts.game.current_turn < _ctx.accounts.player_game_record.current_turn {
    return Err(ErrorCode::TurnAlreadySubmitted.into());
};

//for all army accounts that have been passed in using remaining_accounts, check that the army x and y position matched the from_x and from_y in the move action

let mut no_armies_passed = false;
let mut move_not_to_neighbor = false;
let mut not_moving_from_starting_position = false;

_turns.iter().for_each(|move_action| {

    //You must pass in army accounts for each of your armies that is moving
    if _ctx.remaining_accounts.len() == 0 {
        no_armies_passed = true;
    }
    _ctx.remaining_accounts.iter().for_each(|army_account| {
            let army = Account::<Army>::try_from(&army_account).unwrap();
            if army.key() == move_action.army {
                if army.x == move_action.from_x && army.y == move_action.from_y {
                    if !are_hex_neighbors(move_action.from_x, move_action.from_y, move_action.to_x, move_action.to_y) {
                        move_not_to_neighbor = true;
                    } else {
                        //msg!("Army x: {}, y: {}", army.x, army.y);
                    }
                } else {
                    not_moving_from_starting_position = true;
                }
            }
    });
});

if no_armies_passed {
    return Err(ErrorCode::NoArmiesPassed.into());
}
if move_not_to_neighbor {
    return Err(ErrorCode::MoveNotToNeighbor.into());
}
if not_moving_from_starting_position {
    return Err(ErrorCode::NotMovingFromStartingPosition.into());
}

player_turn.game_id = _ctx.accounts.player_game_record.game_id;
player_turn.player = _ctx.accounts.player.key();
player_turn.game_turn = _ctx.accounts.player_game_record.current_turn;
player_turn.moves = _turns;
player_turn.bump = _ctx.bumps.turn_moves_record;

//Update player turn as this turn has been submitted
let player_record = &mut _ctx.accounts.player_game_record;
player_record.current_turn = player_record.current_turn + 1;

//Update game with hexes and coordinates to process.  Game turn can only be incremented once all armies and hexes have been processed
let game = &mut _ctx.accounts.game;

//for each army in _turns add to game.armies_to_process if not already in list
player_turn.moves.iter().for_each(|move_action| {
    if !game.armies_to_process.iter().any(|&a| a == move_action.army)  {
        game.armies_to_process.push(move_action.army);
    }
});

//Create coordinates from each move's to_x and to_y then add to game.hexes_to_process if not already in list
let mut hexes_to_process: Vec<Coordinates> = Vec::new();
player_turn.moves.iter().for_each(|move_action| {
    let coordinate = Coordinates { x: move_action.to_x, y: move_action.to_y };
    if !game.hexes_to_process.iter().any(|c| c.x == coordinate.x && c.y == coordinate.y)  {
        hexes_to_process.push(coordinate);
    }
});
game.hexes_to_process.append(&mut hexes_to_process);

Ok(())
```

}

```
#[instruction(turns: Vec<MoveAction>)]
pub struct SubmitPlayerTurn<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub player: Signer<'info>,   
    #[account(mut)] 
    pub player_game_record: Account<'info, PlayerGameRecord>,        
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = player,
        space = 8 + TurnMovesRecord::MAXIMUM_SIZE, seeds = [
            b"turn-moves-record".as_ref(), 
            player_game_record.game_id.key().as_ref(),
            player.key().as_ref(),
            &player_game_record.current_turn.to_le_bytes()
            ],
        bump
    )]        
    pub turn_moves_record: Account<'info, TurnMovesRecord>,    
    #[account(mut)] 
    pub game: Account<'info, Game>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>
}

//Utlilty functions
fn are_hex_neighbors(x1: u8, y1: u8, x2: u8, y2: u8) -> bool {
    // Calculate the absolute distance between the x and y coordinates
    let dx = (x1 as i16 - x2 as i16).abs();
    let dy = (y1 as i16 - y2 as i16).abs();
    msg!("x1: {}, y1: {}, x2: {}, y2: {}", x1, y1, x2, y2);
    // Two hexagons are neighbors if the absolute difference in x and y coordinates
    // is no more than 1, and the sum of those differences is no more than 2
    dx <= 1 && dy <= 1 && dx + dy <= 2
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`remaining_accounts` usage in `anchor-lang 0.29.0` requires explicit lifetime annotions:

```
pub fn submit_player_turn<'c: 'info, 'info>(
    ctx: Context<'_, '_, 'c, 'info, SubmitPlayerTurn>,
    turns: Vec<MoveAction>, 
) -> Result<()> {
```

**Note:** `_` prefix for identifiers in Rust indicates that you don't want to deal with the values but you seem to be using both `_ctx` and `_turns` parameters so I've removed the prefix in the solution above.

[Example](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/dfee9589fd56f9aa1a52aa949507b70035482857/tests/misc/programs/remaining-accounts/src/lib.rs#L25-L27)